# Ao relacionar duas tabelas, o correto é do lado do SQL, PHP ou tanto faz?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, desempenho

Tenho essa dúvida do que é preferencial fazer quando preciso de dados das duas tabelas para obter o resultado.

Sempre fazia a comparação no PHP, mas aprendi os comandos de relacionamento de SQL que poderiam ajudar. Qual é a forma mais correta de se fazer, referente ao tempo de execução, padrão e desempenho?

Eu fazia assim:

```
 <?php
          $consultaRecomendados=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM  hf_recomendados");
          $consultaRecomendados->execute();
          $resultadoRecomendados=$consultaRecomendados->fetchAll();
          foreach($resultadoRecomendados as $produtoRecomendado){
               $contultaProdutoRecomendado=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM  hf_produtos WHERE id=:id");
               $contultaProdutoRecomendado->execute(array(":id"=>$produtoRecomendado['idProduto']));
               $resultadoProdutoRecomendado=$contultaProdutoRecomendado->fetch();
                echo $resultadoProdutoRecomendado['nome']; 
          }
          ?>
```

E passei a fazer assim:

```
  <?php
              $contultaRecomendados=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM  hf_recomendados r JOIN  hf_produtos p
ON r.idProduto=p.id");
              $contultaRecomendados->execute();
              $resultadoRecomendados=$contultaRecomendados->fetchAll();
              foreach($resultadoRecomendados as $produtoRecomendado){
                  echo $produtoRecomendado['nome'];
              }
      ?>
```

Há alguma forma melhor ou mais correta? Que considerações técnicas devo ter?

Comment: Linha de código é irrelevante. Um código eficiente de 100 linhas geralmente vale mais que um código porco de 2 linhas, a não ser em raros casos. De qq forma, o 1o exemplo seu é uma falha de programação, mesmo funcionando. O 2o caso está delegando a tarefa para o lugar certo.

Comment: Então, por isso que me veio essa dúvida...

Comment: Veja que no primeiro caso você está solicitando uma série de queries ao servidor, sem a mínima otimização. No segundo caso, é uma query só, e a relação é feita no servidor. Se fizer um teste com muitos dados vai perceber uma diferença absurda até de velocidade. Não vou te afirmar que NUNCA deve ser feito do 1o jeito, mas em situações normais não há razão e nem deve. E se um dia precisar, compensa fazer uma query só interna, e usar bind. (e se for MySQL, esquecer esse negócio de PDO, que é uma camada desnecessária e ineficaz especialmente nestes casos)

Comment: Porque diz que "o 1o exemplo seu é uma falha de programação"?

Comment: Pq é extremamente estressante para a execução de script fazer uma série de queries dentro de um loop - a diferença em performance é brutal, e perde a atomicidade. Você pode ter variação dos dados entre um select e outro, gerando uma série de inconsistências. Tem outros problemas também. Se ninguem postar algo legal te explicando, e sobrar um tempo, tento elaborar algo.

Comment: Compreendi. Não gosto de mesmo de fazer várias coisas dentro de um loop. Passa uma sensação de maior peso. É a mesma sensação de se utilizar loop entro de outro loop

Comment: Loop dentro de Loop se usado normalmente não tem problema. Desde que seja adequado para o caso especifico, claro.

Comment: E dependendo do tamanho de cada loop também. Obrigado Bacco, de qualquer forma já ajudou bastante

Comment: Só um comentário, o primeiro exemplo só deve ser usado se e somente se não existir outro recurso

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, você diz isso a respeito do desempenho? algo que complemente esse seu comentário?

Comment: É mais na linha do que o @bacco disse, nunca diga que você nunca precisará usar algum recurso do tipo, mas se puder evitar, é a melhor decisão pensando em desempenho

Comment: O JOIN do SQL serve justamente para evitar que o software seja responsável por essa junção de dados.

Comment: Se quer eficiência e delegar responsabilidade de manipular os dados para o teu códio, trabalhe com arquivos "txt", pois esta matando o propósito de um SGBD

Comment: Você precisa analisar, fazer um `join` pode ser desnecessário. Tudo que o @Bacco disse eu concordo, entretanto o `join` deve ser feito apenas se naquele momento a informação for relevante, por exemplo, uma lista de registros em que existe um botão "editar". Para a lista não vou fazer o `join` se a informação for irrelevante, então nesse caso só faço o `join` quando o cliente clicar em editar. Estou a fazer mais de uma query a base de dados, é verdade, mas nesse caso há ganho de desempenho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### De uma forma resumida, o melhor é usar o SGBD para juntar as consultas.

Toda vez que você executa uma consulta em um banco de dados ele fará basicamente o seguinte:

1. Interpretar o comando SQL para saber se a sintaxe está correta e se todos os objetos estão disponíveis para execução. Depois converter o SQL para uma estrutura de álgebra relacional.
2. Executar uma análise para fazer um plano de execução da consulta para separar as partes e definir a ordem de execução. Isso envolve decidir quais índices estão disponíveis e quais algorítimos são mais eficientes para fazer a junção das tabelas, baseado nas estatísticas internas que ele coleta do banco como quantidade de registros, índices, etc.
3. Executar cada parte do algorítimo e juntar cada resultado para então disponibilizar o resultado para o chamador, onde ele poderá fazer o "*fetch*" dos dados.

Então, quando você coloca o ***JOIN*** dentro da consulta SQL você está dizendo para o banco de dados resolver para você essas junções utilizando o melhor mecanismo possível e ele usará o código dele, que internamente é otimizado para fazer isso.

Se você escolhe fazer o trabalho que ele faria internamente, é bem provável que o seu código seja menos eficiente. Existem várias formas de fazer *JOINs* entre tabelas e esse é um dos pontos de maior problema para um banco de dados relacional resolver. Até mesmo a forma como você escreve suas consultas, se usa *JOIN* ou *Subquery*, se usa um operador *IN* ou um *EXISTS* afeta internamente o tempo de execução porque muda o jeito como o banco executa a consulta.

Se quiser se aprofundar no assunto pesquise sobre "Álgebra Relacional" e "Otimização de Consultas" e achará bastante material interessante.

Comment: Obrigado Pagotti, era a resposta que eu esperava. Grato também pelas indicações :)

Comment: @LocalHost :) Se puder, marca a resposta como sendo a correta para sua pergunta ou caso queira, pode esperar para ver outras respostas que virão.

Comment: Eu estava esperando, mas essa acho que ja foi suficiente :)